# ng-repeat is not showing data.... error(angular.min.js:123 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/ngRepeat/dupes?

Tags: php, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat in the option tag to generation multiple options.
but it is not working properly.

//Below is my Angular js code

```
      $http.get("assign_leads_1.php?dummydata=2").then(function (response)
        {
            alert(response.data);
            $scope.bdes = response.data;
        });



Below is the html code
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Assign To: </label> 
<select ng-model="bde_tuid" class="form-control">
                <option  ng-repeat="bde in bdes" value="{{bde.tuid}}" >
                    {{bde.xyz}}
                </option>
            </select>
```

// Below is the php code for fetching data from database

```
    require_once 'dbcon.php';      
    $query ="select tuid,username as xyz from tuser where category 
 ='employee'";
    $result=  mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $data[]=$row;
    }

    print json_encode($data);
    }
```

Comment: what you get result alert(response.data); ?

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
<option  ng-repeat="bde in bdes" value="{{bde.tuid}}" >
```

to

```
<option  ng-repeat="bde in bdes track by $index" value="{{bde.tuid}}" >
```